# To query yesterday records from the Parse table using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsdate

I'm going to develop the piece of code to query all the records created yesterday. Well I know it's something very trial. Nevertheless it's one million question for me right now because I'm novice in programming. Below the SWIFT code that doesn't work properly though. For backend I use Parse.com.

```
var yesterday = NSDate() - 1.day.ago // 1.day.ago isn't valid but what I need.

var query = PFQuery(className:"score") // table name is score
query.whereKey("createdAt", equalTo:"yesterday")
```

Help please! As always sooner you help higher your chances to win the Tesla Model S Lottery! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pretty cool new attribute of `NSCalendar` called `dateByAddingUnit` to easily get yesterday's date:

```
let today = NSDate()
let yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay,
                                                              value: -1,
                                                              toDate: today,
                                                              options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
```

Where you set `.CalendarUnitDay` as the calendar unit you wish to add/subtract by and the value of -1 to indicate the change you want for that calendar unit.

But the problem with your query is that it specifically requests that a `PFObject`'s "createdAt" date equals a specific time, not that the `PFObject` was created at anytime during that day. So I suggest you create two constraints in your query -- a greater than and a less than between midnight (the start of the day) yesterday and midnight (the start of the day) today so that the query will return all the results in between.

**Update:**

To get the start of yesterday and today, i.e. midnight, (converted to GMT to match the dates in the parse database, though that line can be removed if that's not your intent) here's what you can do:

```
var today = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

let preservedComponents = NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit
today = calendar.dateFromComponents(calendar.components(preservedComponents, fromDate: today))!
var yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: -1, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
```

Then to perform your query:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"score") // table name is score
query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo: yesterday)
query.whereKey("createdAt", lessThan: today)
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! Could you please hint how to create those constraints?

Comment: @Maga Yeah sure... I'm at dinner now, but I'll write up a suggestion for you a little later.

Comment: @Maga OK, I've made the update. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Maga there was a problem with the syntax? I ran it on my own in xcode before posting and it worked for me...

Comment: thank you once again! To be honest I couldn't apply the code you provided because I saw the syntaxis you are using for the first time. My learning Swift is still in progress. Some day in next future I'll definitely be bak to your suggestion to get max out of it. Nevertheless I did try your code and get back in console the value of `query` is `<PFQuery: 0x7fa188c9c530>` So I guess your code is correct. I'm just confused a bit. I thought the return should be a dictionary. Could you please to clarify?

Comment: @Maga The return of what? The query? Depending on the method you use, your query should return a PFObject or an array of PFObjects.

Comment: yes, I meant the query return. Now I got it! I use `println(query)` :(( Where can I find all the methods of a PFObject? Any shortcut for that? Thx in advance!

Comment: By the way my approach how deal with the issue changed to developing the cloud function to return only the number to the client. The cloud function I've developed is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378965/to-call-the-cloud-function-from-ios-app I'd appreciate much if you take a look!

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
extension NSDate {
    func xDays(x:Int) -> NSDate {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: x, toDate: self, options: [])!
    }
}

let today              = NSDate()
let yesterday          = NSDate().xDays(-1)
let dayBeforeYesterday = NSDate().xDays(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var yesterday = NSDate.date() - 1.days

var query = PFQuery(className:"score") // table name is score
query.whereKey("createdAt", equalTo:yesterday)
```

Pay attention at `equalTo:yesterday` without quotes

Answer (score 0):

Simply try below code. It works fine in iOS7 and iOS8

```
let today = NSDate()
let tomorrow = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)
let yesterday = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60)
```