# To call the cloud function from iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform

I've developed the cloud function to count the number of the votes within last day.

```
// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:

Parse.Cloud.define("confidenceRating", function(request, response) {
    // To define vars yesterday and today
    var today = new Date();
    var yesterday = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

    // "score" is the table's name       
    var query = new Parse.Query("score");

    // filter the query, 2 filters to be applied
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", yesterday);
    query.lessThan("createdAt", today);

    // perfom the action
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            var votes = results.length;
            response.success(votes);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("something went wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

I deployed the code successfully. But how to develop SWIFT code to call the function? Unfortinately no Swift example for that purpose at Parse.com. Please help me!

Upd. 1. I'm using the code suggested by @rickerbh

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("confidenceRating", withParameters: nil) { results, error in
  if error != nil {
    // Your error handling here
  } else {
    // Deal with your results (votes in your case) here.
  }
}
```

But I've gotten the error

```
2014-12-12 12:19:52.399 Rating[4082:166266] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]' *** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x012d3946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some swift code that calls cloud code functions.

```
let parameters = ["": ""]
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("confidenceRating", withParameters: parameters) { results, error in
  if error != nil {
    // Your error handling here
  } else {
    // Deal with your results (votes in your case) here.
  }
}
```

Comment: that crashes compiler ((

Comment: @Maga Maybe pass in an empty dictionary as the parameter. And what's the error message from your compiler? It doesn't crash the compiler for me...

Comment: 2014-12-12 12:19:52.399 Rating[4082:166266] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x012d3946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182

Comment: @Maga That doesn't look like a compiler crash. It looks like a runtime crash. Can you update your question with the code you've implemented to call the function?

Comment: @Maga Ah, it looks like you definitely need to pass in some parameters. Check the updated code block.